# strange behaviour in R when calling to a function inside a for loop

Tags: r, function

I have the following schema in R:

```
functionA<-function(dataA)
{
    #do something
    #no return value
    functionB(dataC)
}

functionB<-function(dataB)
{
    #do something
    #no return value
}

for (i in 1:5)
{
     functionA(list[i])
     print ("message")
}
```

The problem that I have is that it only evaluates the first value and even only prints the word "message" only once. I think that is because functionB is not returning to functionA, but is that necessary? I mean the for loop should not continue evaluating the other instructions. I have tried the code by commenting the line

```
functionA(list[i])
```

and in that case it prints the message 5 times. What it can be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Works for me as it did for Arun.  How are you running R (command line, gui, etc) and are you dead certain you ran the exact code you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's not what I get.

```
functionA<-function(dataA) {
    #do something
    #no return value
    functionB(dataC)
}

functionB<-function(dataB) {
    #do something
    #no return value
    print("in here")
}

for (i in 1:5) {
    functionA(list[i])
    print ("message")
}

[1] "in here"
[1] "message"
[1] "in here"
[1] "message"
[1] "in here"
[1] "message"
[1] "in here"
[1] "message"
[1] "in here"
[1] "message"
```

Comment: Yo, dude -- explain why you accepted this answer: what's different from what you posted?